# Link for downloading folder

Tags: web, download, directory

I have a folder `my_folder`, and inside of that folder is a file `my_file`. I would like to create a link `Download my folder` on my website, so that when the user clicks on it, the user's file directory comes up and the user can choose where to put `my_folder` (which contains `my_file`.) How can I implement this functionality?

I know that to allow the user to download a file, I can simply link to that file. But what about a folder?

Comment: You'll need to compress that folder's contents into a zipped folder, and then allow them to downloaded that zip.

Comment: @Vulcan Sure, that's clearly a way to do it, but it's rather inconvenient for the user to have to unzip. Is there a way to directly download the folder?

Comment: Or you could make a TAR archive on-the-fly. No decompression cost (as for ZIP) and they were just meant for this type of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From personal experience I have not seen a way to download a whole directory. You would probably have to dynamically zip the folder up and make the resulting zip downloadable.

In HTML 5 you could use something like this to download a single file

```
<a href="/files/name-of-pdf.pdf" download="name-of-pdf">Download Your PDF</a>
```

The download attribute will force a download dialog for the user.

Hope this puts you on the right track and maybe someone can prove me wrong on that directory download.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to create a direct link to download a folder,
But this is a great alternative if you want users to download your "my_folder"

1. upload your folder to any online file storage service provider (like *Google Drive* or *Dropbox*).
2. Place that inside another folder say "parentfolder"
3. Get the link for the "parentfolder" and add that into your website's HTML (make sure to change viewing setting to *anyone with the link*)

You'll probably want to set :

```
  target="_blank"
```

in your 'a' tag

Now, when user clicks the link it redirects to your drive and shows "my_folder" which they can either download or open to see the "my_file"